# google drive fails to sync one file

Tags: google-backup-and-sync

I am using Google backup and sync between a few computers and now and again it starts failing to sync one file among only one of these computers.

Right now, it's stuck retrying to download that file (~6Mbs).

Of course I can uninstall/re-install backup and sync but it's a pain...

While writing this, it just finished its last failed attempt and there is a msg "You do not have permission to sync these files"...?

I am admin on all PCs involved and it is the only PC having problem...

Any idea?

Comment: You are probably trying to sync an unallowed extension.Google has a scanner which blocks possible viruses and unallowed extensions. The other option is that you have run out of space.

Comment: it does sync on several computers (still now) and was fine until recently on this particular PC (I think)

Comment: What is the file name and extension? Is the file already in google, or is not possible to upload it?

Comment: It's a Microsoft Money file (old software).
It's already uploaded to Google Drive and I updated it yesterday evening from my "main" computer.

Out of curiosity, I checked backup and sync on a third computer and it just downloaded the update without problem... BUT reports the same kind of error on yet another folder! ("You do not have permission to sync these files"... not sure whether I can trust the error msg though)

Comment: I suggest replacing Google drive with a different software, Google drive pressures your computer a lot too. it's best to have an external drive and use bvckup v2. Or you can use mega.nz and their 50gb of free storage.

Comment: Thx. I'll have a look at mega.nz but I like the fact that most people have google drive... that allows me to share this file with my sister in a different country...

Comment: Mega works better if they allow access from your country, if not just download their desktop app, the web based version will get stuck at the mega logo. Dropbox works from all countries.

Comment: For my third computer, I solved the "folder" problem by creating a dummy file in that folder. That seemed to solve the issue. For the initial issue, it was due to an undesired process I was not aware off.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, the file was kept opened by an undesired background application (Microsoft Money Express).
Once I killed that application, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may lie in this file, you can check if this file is being used or opened by other software. Or, make sure your user account should have full control permission for the Google Drive folder. Here is a post from this forum that talks about the Windows file permissions/ownership are preventing Google Drive syncing between computers, which is very similar to your situation, you can refer to it: [Windows file permissions/ownership are preventing me syncing between computers](https://superuser.com/questions/1489671/windows-file-permissions-ownership-are-preventing-me-syncing-between-computers)
If your problem can't be solved by checking the files, you may need to reinstall Google Backup and Sync or use a [Google Backup and Sync alternative](https://cloud.ubackup.com/articles/google-backup-and-sync-alternative-6688.html) to sync your files.